# Multiply out a multidimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to multiply out a list with variable inputs, eg
`ipList = [[4,6,1],[[5,6,1],[1,2,1]],[14,15,1]]`
Notice that element 1 & 3 is 1 item, but element 2 has 2 items (this is variable and can even have more)

This list shows the values (start, stop, step), so there are 3 inputs here
(1) [4..6],(step 1) 
(2) [[5..6], [1..2]],(step 1, step 1) 
(3) [14..15] (step 1)
I would like a cartesian plane of these values.
A dataframe that holds (in this case 3 columns) with each possible value.

however in this case the end result should look like

```
C1   C2   C3
4, [5,1], 14
4, [5,2], 14
4, [6,1], 14
4, [6,2], 14
5, [5,1], 14
5, [5,2], 14
5, [6,1], 14
5, [6,2], 14
4, [5,1], 15
4, [5,2], 15
4, [6,1], 15
4, [6,2], 15
5, [5,1], 15
5, [5,2], 15
5, [6,1], 15
5, [6,2], 15
```

Another (simpler example) would be:
```ipList = [[8,9,1],[[1,2,1],[1,2,1]] ]```
So theres 2 elements here:
(1) [8,9,1] - 8, 9 (start-8, stop-9, step-1)
(2) [[1,2,1],[1,2,1]]  values of [1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]

So the end result would be

```
8, [1,1]
8, [1,2]
8, [2,1]
8, [2,2]
9, [1,1]
9, [1,2]
9, [2,1]
9, [2,2]
```

The idea is that you have an element
[el1, el2, el3] but these have variable sizes.

Ive tried quite a few things but I believe there must be a much easier way
Ive seen many threads that make a Cartesian plane but can only do it with single values,
I've built a frame that shows each row and thought of multiplying it out from there.

```
  Start Indi Stop Level Step<br>
0     4    0    6     0    1<br>
1     5  1.1    7     1    1<br>
2     1  1.2    2     1    1<br>
3    14    2   15     2    1<br>
```

I believe I can create some kind of loop that also goes through each of the above
rows and then use pandas to merge it, however Im still getting a bit stuck on this.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2,on='key')[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
Out[19]: 
   col1  col2    col3
0     1     3  [5, 1]
1     1     3  [5, 2]
2     2     4  [5, 1]
3     2     4  [5, 2]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you may be provide the end dataframe with more values so it's clearer on the pattern?

Comment: updated the question with the full result

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the desired output here, can you post the output you're expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a customized `generator` to iterate through a customized format is something quite reasonable and common in practice. Just go for this if nobody manages to find a magical spell.

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def gen(ipList):
    l1 = list(range(ipList[0][0], ipList[0][1] + 1, ipList[0][2]))
    l2 = list(range(ipList[1][0][0], ipList[1][0][1] + 1, ipList[1][0][2]))
    l3 = list(range(ipList[1][1][0], ipList[1][1][1] + 1, ipList[1][1][2]))
    l4 = list(range(ipList[2][0], ipList[2][1] + 1, ipList[2][2]))
    for tup in itertools.product(l1, l2, l3, l4):
        yield tup[0], [tup[1], tup[2]], tup[3]

ipList = [[4,6,1],[[5,6,1],[1,2,1]],[14,15,1]]
```

All the entries can be listed using `list(gen())`:

```
ans = list(gen(ipList))
```

A dataframe can be constructed easily

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ans, columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"])  # column names are optional
```

However, the most notable advantage of a generator is that you can iterate through the Cartesian product entries one-by-one without producing the entire list. This can save a lot of resource when the size of Cartesian product is huge.

```
for tup in gen(ipList):
    # do something with tup, e.g.
    # print(tup)
```

### Outcome

```
ans
Out[14]: 
[(4, [5, 1], 14),
 (4, [5, 1], 15),
 (4, [5, 2], 14),
 (4, [5, 2], 15),
 (4, [6, 1], 14),
 (4, [6, 1], 15),
 (4, [6, 2], 14),
 (4, [6, 2], 15),
 (5, [5, 1], 14),
 (5, [5, 1], 15),
 (5, [5, 2], 14),
 (5, [5, 2], 15),
 (5, [6, 1], 14),
 (5, [6, 1], 15),
 (5, [6, 2], 14),
 (5, [6, 2], 15),
 (6, [5, 1], 14),
 (6, [5, 1], 15),
 (6, [5, 2], 14),
 (6, [5, 2], 15),
 (6, [6, 1], 14),
 (6, [6, 1], 15),
 (6, [6, 2], 14),
 (6, [6, 2], 15)]

df
Out[15]: 
    col1    col2  col3
0      4  [5, 1]    14
1      4  [5, 1]    15
2      4  [5, 2]    14
3      4  [5, 2]    15
4      4  [6, 1]    14
5      4  [6, 1]    15
6      4  [6, 2]    14
7      4  [6, 2]    15
8      5  [5, 1]    14
9      5  [5, 1]    15
10     5  [5, 2]    14
11     5  [5, 2]    15
12     5  [6, 1]    14
13     5  [6, 1]    15
14     5  [6, 2]    14
15     5  [6, 2]    15
16     6  [5, 1]    14
17     6  [5, 1]    15
18     6  [5, 2]    14
19     6  [5, 2]    15
20     6  [6, 1]    14
21     6  [6, 1]    15
22     6  [6, 2]    14
23     6  [6, 2]    15
```

Comment: Thank you very much!